# How to protect a Unity Project Template?

Tags: unity, c#, encryption

We are preparing a working environment(Workspace) in Unity3d that contains several assets, settings, and scripts. The problem is that we want to protect our assets. How is it possible? I know that settings or models are not protectable. But how do I protect my code in a way that the client can use it but not see it?

Comment: I would not know any good technical way to do this. My approach to this problem would be to have our lawyer write a really scary sounding NDA / license and demand that the people who receive those templates sign it.

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible. The managed C# that Unity uses is pretty easy to decompile to readable source, even if you distribute it as a pre-compiled library. I think you should give up on code secrecy as a goal, and find another route to serve your business needs, like the legal approach that Philipp recommends.

Comment: converting your code to simple DLL is not an option? easily decompile?

Comment: If there's a particular piece if code you're worried about, you could essentially make that its own application that your Unity scripts communicate with via TCP or some other interface. That has a lot of drawbacks, however, and won't work for anything performance critical, so I hesitate to make that an answer.

Comment: most of the script i want to protect. initially, i am trying to convert my scripts to DLL. But above comment suggested that dlls are easily decompiled.